# Bootstrap drop down with check box(s) allowing for multiple check boxes instead of just one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap drop down menu that allows a user to add a check box next to an item in the drop down list. However, the user is able to add multiple check boxes - the desired behavior is that a user should only be able to select one check box. If a user has selected one check box the other check box should be removed.

```js
$("document").ready(function() {

  $('.dropdown-menu').on('click', function(e) {
    if($('.checkbox').count() > 1){
           if($(this).hasClass('dropdown-menu-form')) {
          e.stopPropagation();
      }
    }

  });
});
```

```css
.dropdown-menu-form {
  padding: 5px 10px 0;
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle btn" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
       Toggle dropdown
      <b class="caret"></b>
   </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-form" role="menu">
    <li>
      <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox">Checkbox 1
      </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox">Checkbox 2
      </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox">Checkbox 2
      </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox">Checkbox 2
      </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox">Checkbox 2
      </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox">Checkbox 3
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I tried to implement something with the count of the number of klass of `.checkbox` however that did not work. I am just looking to have the behavior if the user clicks a check box the previous check box will be removed.

Comment: That is what radio buttons are for. Any reason you want checkbox instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkboxes are created to allow multiple checks, think of it as `you can have this, that, and that`. You are looking for a radio button. Radio buttons are treated as a `you get this` or `you get that`.

**Try This**

```
<li>
        <label class="radio-btn">
            <input type="radio">
            Radio 1
        </label>
    </li>
```

**JS**

```
$("document").ready(function() {

  $('.dropdown-menu').on('click', function(e) {
    if($('.radio-btn').count() > 1){
           if($(this).hasClass('dropdown-menu-form')) {
          e.stopPropagation();
      }
    }

  });
});
```